# Cannot update Column Windowed function error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Assuming that I had previously declared a table called #temp which has count as NULL values, and later on I wanted to update that column in my Script how would I do that?

```
count --- CAM 

 1        201 
 1        2
 1        2012
 2        20
```

I have the update statement which would be:

Update #temp set [count]= ((ROW_NUMBER() over(order by CAM desc)-1/3)+1

However, it gives me the following error:
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

I have tried many different ways using a select statement, but no luck!. Any help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you want to do, although `count` is a bit of an odd column name here given the data it seems to hold:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT (row_number() OVER(ORDER BY CAM DESC) - 1)/3 + 1 AS [count],
        CAM
    FROM #temp
)
UPDATE #temp
SET #temp.[count] = cte.[count]
FROM #temp
INNER JOIN cte ON #temp.CAM = cte.CAM
```

Note I've also pulled the `/3` outside of the parentheses - I believe this is what you've intended.

This will work as long as `CAM` is unique.